# below ajax is not executing, I don't understand why

Tags: ajax, spring, validation

I am relatively new to ajax and I am trying validate email and mobile through response body check mobile email in my controller, I am unable to spot my mistake, since ajax syntax is new to me, can anyone help me out in right direction? Thankyou

```
$('#email','#mobile').blur(function(){
    alert("in validation");
    var enteredEmail = $("#email").val();
    var enteredMobile = $("#mobile").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : window.location + "checkmobileemail",
            data : {email:enteredEmail , mobile:enteredMobile},
            success : function(result) {
            if (result == 'Duplicate') {
                $("#emailMsg","#mobileMsg").html("Email or Mobile already exists");
                $("#email","#mobile").focus();
                $("#addButton","#saveChanges").prop("disabled",true);
            } else {
                $("#emailMsg","#mobileMsg").html("");
                $().prop("disabled",false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkmobileemail",method= RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String checkMobileEmail(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
    String mobile = req.getParameter("mobile");
    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    String id = req.getParameter("id");
    System.err.println("id "+ id + "mobile: "+ mobile + " , email: " + email);
    return service.findByEmailAndMobile(email,mobile);
}
```

Service method:

```
@Override
public String findByEmailAndMobile(String email, String mobile) {
    Customer customer = repository.findByEmailAndMobile(email,mobile);
    return (customer == null)? "Unique" : "Duplicate";
}
```

Comment: can you try this  , url : 'window.location.href + "/" + "checkmobileemail"'  and set contentType : 'application/json' also set 'type : "POST"'

Comment: Type is actually set to 'GET' in controller so it can compare entered email and mobile from database and display message, do I need to put this ajax into validate function? because it is below it

Comment: can you post your controller method

Comment: You can see it.

Comment: did you set your url to 'window.location.href + "/" + "checkmobileemail"' ?

Comment: yes I tried it, It is basically not reaching to controller and I don't know why

Comment: does your controller have requestmapping ?

Comment: yes it has "/customer" and I have tried "/customer/checkmobileemail" too, but the out put is same

Comment: I have updated service method too in my question

Comment: so your url should be = 'window.location.href + "/customer/checkmobileeemail"'

Comment: whats the exception you get on console or spring logs?

Comment: since I have set email and mobile in database with unique constraints, it throws java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this with class attribute. Multiple id will not work with the version you are using it seems.

for ex:-

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".test").change(function(){
Your code and use change method. Do not use blur.
});
});

HTML=>

It will work. Thanks!

Comment: also set url : 'window.location.href + "/" + "checkmobileemail"' and set contentType : 'application/json' also set 'type : "POST"'

Comment: skype => akash.upadhyay66  Connect me i will see it